# Atualizar o restante de uma tabela a partir dos dados contidos em uma linha

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, sql-select

A figura abaixo explica bem o que quero tentar fazer (e o que tentei fazer mas não deu certo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, preciso atualizar algumas linhas de uma tabela com os mesmos dados contidos em uma linha (especificamente, as colunas bankId, proj_day e liq_day, em vermelho na figura acima). Reparem que a coluna id é igual à coluna entryID das demais linhas que precisam ser preenchidas (em verde na figura acima). A query que montei não deu certo e há centenas de dados como esse que precisam ser atualizados dessa forma.

Alguém saberia me dar uma luz? Obrigado!

Comment: A imagem é uma boa ilustração, mas inclua o código do seu sql em formato texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei curioso não ter funcionado, apesar de na querie  estar declarado com dois bancos distintos, na sua pergunta não deixou claro se precisa fazer isso relacionando duas tabelas em bancos distintos ou se poderia montar com um auto relacionamento dentro da mesma tabela em apenas uma base de dados. Então peguei o seu exemplo e montei uma tabela de teste como abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deixei com o valor default **null** os campos que deveriam ser atualizados em seguida construi a querie:

```
 UPDATE flux AS A INNER JOIN flux AS B ON A.entryId = B.id 
 SET 
     A.proj_day = B.proj_day, 
     A.liq_day = B.liq_day, 
     A.bankId = B.bankId 
 WHERE A.userid = 307 AND A.entryID > 0
```

Montei um auto-relacionamento seguindo a sua querie, a diferença é que a querie acima relaciona ela com ela mesmo **(auto-relacionamento)** pelo campo **entryID** e **id**.

Em seguida rodei a querie e funciona perfeito como imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu acho que está errando é que está utilizando dois bancos de dados distintos, possivelmente criou uma nova base para não afetar os dados que estão sobre produção e para ter um ambiente de testes. Como não especificou o erro, em sua pergunta, ficou difícil de te ajudar mais. Utilizando o auto-relacionamento acima funcionaria perfeito!

Comment: Você está certo! Na verdade a query estava correta e não precisava eu ter duplicado a mesma base de dados para fazer o inner join (de fato, esqueci de mencionar isso na pergunta). Além do mais, eu estava com a visão do banco de dados que não recebe a atualização. Que bagunça a minha... Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento!